# Is this sentence more than one clause?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, clauses

The following sentence is from a text extract:

> If necessary, I myself will put him off the train.

I am trying to analyse the sentence and identify it as being a simple, compound, complex or compound-complex sentence. However, I'm unsure of how to go about this, particularly due to the reflexive pronoun "myself"; the two objects, "him" and "train"; and the phrase "if necessary".

This is my analysis:

> **If necessary** [phrase], **I** [subject] myself **will** [verb] **put** [verb] **him** [indir. obj.] off the **train** [dir. obj.] = 1 CLAUSE = SIMPLE SENTENCE

Is it correct? Could it be broken down further?

Comment: How many non-auxiliary verbs? One: _put_. Hence one clause. If you wanted to, you could insert the omitted _it is_ in the _if_ phrase, reconstructing the clause it's related to, and then there'd be two clauses.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you. I'm glad that I was able to get a response from a professional linguist. I actually discussed this with a friend of mine; he argued that the only correct way to parse the sentence was to divide it into two clauses, as you referenced. Whereas I and a teacher agreed that it could be considered one clause when "if necessary" is not assumed to be elision.

Comment: @JohnLawler "it is" is there; it's just hiding.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of "phrase" do you imagine  "If necessary" to be?
It is actually is an ***[abbreviated (dependent) clause](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130514204016AAHuymO)***, making your sentence a compound sentence, short for:

> If *[it is]* necessary, I myself will put him off the train.

(Alternately, use *[it becomes]*)

Your big clue should be the word "[if](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/if)", a [conjunction](http://www.grammarly.com/blog/conjunctions/) that always introduces a dependent clause.

Most clauses beginning with "if" would form a simple declarative sentence without the if, but in this case the only other word in the clause is the adjective "necessary".

An isolated adjective  can't be a sentence all by itself, can it? Well yes it can, in a way.  A speaker might say just "necessary" as a shortcut for saying ***it is necessary***. Imagine the following exchange:

> *A:* What's it like out there?
>
> *B:* *Cold.* It must be forty below!
>
> *A:* Will you go back out?
>
> *B:* If necessary.

"Cold" is (extra) short for ""It's cold". Of course, that's conversational English, but abbreviated clauses also happen  in longer sentences, where the appearance of things like "it is" begin to clutter up the text.

> ***Unless specifically permitted***, students will stay in the classrooms and out of the halls while class is in session.

There's a more scholarly discussion of abbreviated clauses at  [this link](https://books.google.com/books?id=1cANNCA0jlcC&pg=PA417&lpg=PA417&dq=abbreviated+clauses&source=bl&ots=foO37pwqqM&sig=0o7HoTQyM0y75BgufBxuKZCE0vA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjppPbj-LTVAhUDRSYKHXBEAYMQ6AEIMDAG#v=onepage&q=abbreviated%20clauses&f=false).

A slightly more accessible definition can be found at [ESL Glossary](http://flesl.net/Grammar/new%20glossary(a-l).html) and has a great example

> Jill thought the coat ***left in the car*** was Jack's.

This could be short for

> Jill thought the coat *[which she found]* left in the car was Jack's.

Comment: +1 Good detail and information. I am intrigued by one of your example sentences. Are the clauses as follows? *[Unless specifically permitted], [students will stay in the classrooms] and [students will stay out of the halls]* or can you consider "and out of the halls" a phrase?

Comment: @DogLover That's a full blown prepositional phrase, with "and" as a list separator.

Answer (score 1):

"All clauses contain both a subject and a predicate, which always contains a verb." [Reference](http://www.write.com/writing-guides/general-writing/grammar/clauses-and-phrases/)

The only time a subject is not stated but is understood is the omission of "You" in an imperative, for example, "Call the plumber, please." [Reference](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/sentelmt.htm)

There is no case where both the subject and verb are understood.

Therefore, you are correct that "If necessary" is a phrase and the sentence has only one clause and is therefore simple.

However, "train" is not the direct object. The train is not what will be put somewhere. The direct object is "him" which describes what will be put somewhere. The word "train" is the object of the preposition "off". The phrase "off the train" is a prepositional phrase that is an adverbial phrase since it answers the question where something will be put.

Comment: Sorry, but a clause might have an implied verb. "If necessary" is a clause.